# Extract paths from a diff file

Tags: c#, substring, visual-studio-2019, diff, .net-4.5

I am trying to extract the paths from a diff file using below piece of code:

```
    string diff = "--- //mac/Home/Documents/myFile1.txt\n+++ //mac/Home/Downloads/myFile2.txt\n@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@\n-hol3a2aaaa2!!!!!!\n+hol3aaa2!!!!!!";

    int pos1 = diff.IndexOf("--- ");
    int pos2 = diff.IndexOf("\n+++ ");
    string finalString = diff.Substring(pos1 + 4, pos2 - 4);
    Console.WriteLine(finalString);
    
    pos1 = diff.IndexOf("+++ ");
    pos2 = diff.IndexOf("\n@@");
    finalString = diff.Substring(pos1 + 4, pos2 - 4);
    Console.WriteLine(finalString);
```

First path is successfully extracted but second isn't. What am I doing wrong?

**Output**:

```
//mac/Home/Documents/myFile1.txt
//mac/Home/Downloads/myFile2.txt
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-hol3a2aaaa2!!!!!!
+
```

**Expected**:

```
//mac/Home/Documents/myFile1.txt
//mac/Home/Downloads/myFile2.txt
```

Comment: I think if you use `regex`  it should be able to solve this problem very well. If jules' answer helped you and you accept it, you could click '✔' to mark his reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the substring is defined like this:
public string Substring (int startIndex, int length);

The first one works out fine because Pos1 is correct and the lenght is the first path.
The seconnd one uses Pos1 correct, but the length is Path 1 + Path 2.

To make it easier to understand:

```
string diff = "--- //mac/Home/Documents/myFile1.txt\n+++ //mac/Home/Downloads/myFile2.txt\n@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@\n-hol3a2aaaa2!!!!!!\n+hol3aaa2!!!!!!";

int pos1 = diff.IndexOf("--- ");
int pos2 = diff.IndexOf("\n+++ ");
string finalString = diff.Substring(pos1 + 4, pos2 - 4);
Console.WriteLine(pos1);
Console.WriteLine(pos2);
Console.WriteLine(finalString);

pos1 = diff.IndexOf("+++ ");
pos2 = diff.IndexOf("\n@@");
finalString = diff.Substring(pos1 + 4, pos2 - 4);
Console.WriteLine(pos1);
Console.WriteLine(pos2);
Console.WriteLine(finalString);
```

You will see pos2 in the second time is much bigger than first time.Try

```
string[] tempStringArray = diff.Split('\n');
string finalStringOne = tempStringArray[0].Replace("--- ","");
string finalStringTwo = tempStringArray[1].Replace("+++ ","");
```

Comment: Oh my God! Right! in the second case should be: diff.Substring(pos1 + 4, (pos2 - pos1) - 4);

Comment: Thanks for your approach. In your example you must remove prefixes "--- " and "+++ "

Comment: Oh yeah, true. You could do this by Replace("---","")

Comment: @Ralph I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark the reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: @Piepe Please, correct your post by adding the Replace("---- ","") and Replace("+++ ","") so people who has the same problem can see it updated. A lot of thanks for your support. Your solution works like a charm.

Comment: @Ralph It's done

Answer (score 2):

What else you can use is maybe a Regex-Pattern. E.g.:

```
(?<= )(.*?)(?=\\n)
```

or

```
(?=\/\/)(.*?)(?=\\n)
```

The advantage is, in the future you can use another parts from that string, if you want to expand more features.